# Limits and Continuity of Complex Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking to prove the following:

Let $w_0$, $z_0$, $\in \mathbb{C}$ and let $f$ be a function defined on a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$:
If $lim_{z \rightarrow z_0}$ $f(z) = w_0$, then $lim_{p \rightarrow 0} f(z_0 + p) = w_0$.

Using the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of a limit.

I think that I am supposed to use some for of composition of functions, otherwise I don't see an approach other than just saying that $p= z-z_0$ and substituting. Thanks for any help.

Comment: That $$\lim_{x\to z_0}f(z)=w_0$$ means that the limits exists  and equals that *no matter how* $\;z\;$ approaches $\;z_0\;$ , and since $\;z_0+p\;$ approaches $\;z_0\;$ when $\;p\to 0\;$ we're done

Answer (score 0):

If you want a proof using $\epsilon-\delta,$ you can say that for all $\epsilon >0,$ there exists $\delta>0 $ such that for all $z \in B(z_0,\delta),$ $|f(z)-w_0| < \epsilon$. In particular, if $|p|< \delta,$ then $z_0+\frac{\delta}{2} \in B(z_0,\delta)$ and hence $|f(z_0+\frac{\delta}{2})-w_0| < \epsilon.$